# Use ternary operator for flow control in Java

Tags: java, ternary-operator

The `?:` (ternary) operator can be used instead of an *if-then-else* statement for assignment, but can also be used in some way for flow control? For example,

```
flag ? method1 : method2;
```

Comment: Did you try? What happened?

Comment: Yep. Definitely. Do you have a *specific* problem calling methods in  this way?

Comment: Yes it can. Can you please add some concrete example?

Comment: http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried :)

Comment: Just being pedantic: `? :` is ***a*** ternary operator (an operator that accepts three operands). Its proper name is the *conditional operator*. It happens to be the only ternary operator Java has for now, but...

Comment: Best answer you can get is from the [JLS - 15.25. Conditional Operator ? :](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.25)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, **but**:

1. You have to save the result; you can't just have an expression on its own (in Java; you can in some other languages).
2. The methods can't have a `void` return type.

The type of the conditional expression will depend on the return types of the methods you use. If both return booleans, the type will be boolean; if both are numeric, the result will be numeric; otherwise, the result will be a reference type (e.g., like `Object`).

E.g.:

```
x = flag ? method1() : method2();
```

More in [JLS §15.25 - *Conditional Operator `?` `:`*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.25).

If it were important to you to be able to use the conditional this way (personally, I'd stick with flow control statements), you could define a utility method that looked like this:

```
static void consume(Object o) {
}
```

And then:

```
consume(flag ? method1() : method2());
```

Comment: Aren't all non-void types compatible (use `Object` as common "supertype").

Comment: If your two methods really don't need to return anything, you *could* declare that they return a `Void` object, which I would expect people to realise means that the method doesn't return anything useful - and then you can just plop a `return null;` at the end of each one. However, I'd prefer not to use a ternary in the first place in that scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Probably already answered. But yes, we can use the methods in ternary operation if both the methods are returning same type. Example given below.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        boolean b = true;
        int i = b ? getThis() : getThat();
    }

    public static int getThis() {
        return 1;
    }

    public static int getThat() {
        return 2;
    }
```